# How to solve this internal error in redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine-plugins

When I try to connect to database in Redmine custom workflow, and click on "Save", I get Redmine Internal Error. Please find the code below

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter => "mysql2",
:host => "localhost",
:database => "bitnami_redmine",
:username => "bitnami",
:password => "xxxx"
)
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'


Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Creating scope :sorted. Overwriting existing method User.sorted.
Creating scope :sorted. Overwriting existing method Group.sorted.
Creating scope :system. Overwriting existing method Enumeration.system.
Started GET "/redmine" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-20 12:22:09 +0530
Started GET "/redmine" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-20 12:22:09 +0530
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Current user: anonymous
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (25.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 269.4ms (Views: 46.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.2ms)
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (24.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 270.4ms (Views: 45.4ms | ActiveRecord: 8.9ms)
Started GET "/redmine/logs/index" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:22:46 +0530
Processing by LogsController#index as HTML
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_logs/app/views/logs/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (10.7ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (14.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 38.7ms (Views: 29.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)
Started POST "/redmine/logs/show" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:22:49 +0530
Processing by LogsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gz0tCXsZaIGUygk/zDUmJf4PNCK9uVR+w1OVg8vDUCU=", "path"=>"/home/administrator/new_redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/log/production.log"}
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_logs/app/views/logs/show.html.erb within layouts/admin (4.6ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (7.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23.2ms (Views: 17.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
Started PUT "/redmine/custom_workflows/2" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:29:33 +0530
Processing by CustomWorkflowsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gz0tCXsZaIGUygk/zDUmJf4PNCK9uVR+w1OVg8vDUCU=", "custom_workflow"=>{"name"=>"SMS", "description"=>"", "is_for_all"=>"0", "project_ids"=>[""], "before_save"=>"@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(\r\n              :adapter => \"mysql2\",\r\n              :host => \"192.168.11.27\",\r\n              :database => \"bitnami_redmine\",\r\n              :username => \"root\",\r\n              :password => \"user1234\"\r\n              )", "after_save"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"2"}
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 119.4ms

Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'redmine.test' (using password: YES)):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `connect'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `initialize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
  /home/administrator/new_redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
  /home/administrator/new_redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2378728236099272798__call__2767763288329299403__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:83:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'


Started PUT "/redmine/custom_workflows/2" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:32:48 +0530

Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'redmine.test' (using password: YES)):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `connect'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `initialize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
  /home/administrator/new_redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
  /home/administrator/new_redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2378728236099272798__call__2767763288329299403__callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:83:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.57) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'


Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Creating scope :sorted. Overwriting existing method User.sorted.
Creating scope :sorted. Overwriting existing method Group.sorted.
Creating scope :system. Overwriting existing method Enumeration.system.
Started GET "/redmine" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-20 12:33:13 +0530
Started GET "/redmine" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-20 12:33:13 +0530
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Current user: anonymous
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (25.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 269.2ms (Views: 46.3ms | ActiveRecord: 9.2ms)
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (24.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 268.2ms (Views: 44.9ms | ActiveRecord: 8.9ms)
Started GET "/redmine/custom_workflows/2" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:34:00 +0530
Processing by CustomWorkflowsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
Redirected to http://192.168.11.27:8090/redmine/custom_workflows/2/edit
Completed 302 Found in 19.3ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
Started GET "/redmine/custom_workflows/2/edit" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:34:00 +0530
Processing by CustomWorkflowsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_custom_workflows/app/views/custom_workflows/_form.html.erb (8.5ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_custom_workflows/app/views/custom_workflows/edit.html.erb within layouts/admin (18.6ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (19.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52.0ms (Views: 42.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)
Started GET "/redmine/custom_workflows/2/edit" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:34:04 +0530
Processing by CustomWorkflowsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_custom_workflows/app/views/custom_workflows/_form.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_custom_workflows/app/views/custom_workflows/edit.html.erb within layouts/admin (6.6ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (7.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20.9ms (Views: 15.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
Started GET "/redmine/logs/index" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:34:37 +0530
Processing by LogsController#index as HTML
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_logs/app/views/logs/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (6.6ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (5.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19.3ms (Views: 14.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
Started POST "/redmine/logs/show" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 12:34:39 +0530
Processing by LogsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gz0tCXsZaIGUygk/zDUmJf4PNCK9uVR+w1OVg8vDUCU=", "path"=>"/home/administrator/new_redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/log/production.log"}
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_logs/app/views/logs/show.html.erb within layouts/admin (4.0ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (9.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24.3ms (Views: 18.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
Started GET "/redmine/logs/index" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 13:06:42 +0530
Processing by LogsController#index as HTML
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_logs/app/views/logs/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (5.9ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (5.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20.3ms (Views: 15.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
Started POST "/redmine/logs/show" for 192.168.11.93 at 2015-06-20 13:06:46 +0530
Processing by LogsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gz0tCXsZaIGUygk/zDUmJf4PNCK9uVR+w1OVg8vDUCU=", "path"=>"/home/administrator/new_redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/log/production.log"}
  Current user: shruthi (id=1)
```

This is the log file. I was not able to figure out anything
Please help me to solve this

Comment: At least give us the error log...

Comment: Can you connect to the database using another tool with those parameters?

Comment: I am getting this error when I connect via DB solo  .                             You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@connection = ActiveRecord:Base.establish_connection( :adapter => ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

It looks like the plugin has been installed properly but it is using `redmine.test`. Did you set the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable to production for installing the plugin? Did you modified anything else?

Regards,
Gonzalo

Comment: I am not installing any plugin..I am just trying to connect to mysql datbase..There is something called custom workflow in redmine where ruby code is written and executed.There I tried to connect to databse by writing ruby code which is mentioned above.